# Pyspark: pivot month level records into a single column based quarter level record

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe in the form:

---

```
+---------+-------+------------+------------------+--------+-------+         
| quarter | month | month_rank | unique_customers | units  | sales |
+---------+-------+------------+------------------+--------+-------+
-
|   1     |   1   |     1      |  15              | 30     | 1000  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1     |   2   |     2      |  20              | 35     | 1200  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1     |   3   |     3      |  18              | 40     | 1500  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2     |   4   |     1      |  10              | 25     | 800   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2     |   5   |     2      |  25              | 50     | 2000  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2     |   6   |     3      |  28              | 45     | 1800  |
...
```

I am trying to group on quarter and track the monthly sales in a columnar fashion such as the following:

```
+---------+--------------+------------+------------------+--------+-------+
| quarter | month_rank1 | rank1_unique_customers | rank1_units | rank1_sales | month_rank2 | rank2_unique_customers | rank2_units | rank2_sales | month_rank3 | rank3_unique_customers | rank3_units | rank3_sales |
+---------+--------------+------------+------------------+--------+-------+
|   1     |   1   |  15|30|1000|   2  |20|35|1200  |   3  |18|40|1500
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2     |   4   |  10|25|800 |   5  |25|50|2000  |   6  |28|45|1800
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is this achievable with multiple pivots? I have had no luck creating multiple columns from a pivot. I am thinking I might be able to achieve this result with windowing, but if anyone has run into a similar problem any suggestions would be greatly appriciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use pivot on **`month_rank`** column then **`agg`** other columns.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,1,1,15,30,1000),(1,2,2,20,35,1200),(1,3,3,18,40,1500),(2,4,1,10,25,800),(2,5,2,25,50,2000),(2,6,3,28,45,1800)],["quarter","month","month_rank","unique_customers","units","sales"])

df.show()
#+-------+-----+----------+----------------+-----+-----+
#|quarter|month|month_rank|unique_customers|units|sales|
#+-------+-----+----------+----------------+-----+-----+
#|      1|    1|         1|              15|   30| 1000|
#|      1|    2|         2|              20|   35| 1200|
#|      1|    3|         3|              18|   40| 1500|
#|      2|    4|         1|              10|   25|  800|
#|      2|    5|         2|              25|   50| 2000|
#|      2|    6|         3|              28|   45| 1800|
#+-------+-----+----------+----------------+-----+-----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1=df.\
groupBy("quarter").\
pivot("month_rank").\
agg(first(col("month")),first(col("unique_customers")),first(col("units")),first(col("sales")))

cols=["quarter","month_rank1","rank1_unique_customers","rank1_units","rank1_sales","month_rank2","rank2_unique_customers","rank2_units","rank2_sales","month_rank3","rank3_unique_customers","rank3_units","rank3_sales"]

df1.toDF(*cols).show()
#+-------+-----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
#|quarter|month_rank1|rank1_unique_customers|rank1_units|rank1_sales|month_rank2|rank2_unique_customers|rank2_units|rank2_sales|month_rank3|rank3_unique_customers|rank3_units|rank3_sales|
#+-------+-----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
#|      1|          1|                    15|         30|       1000|          2|                    20|         35|       1200|          3|                    18|         40|       1500|
#|      2|          4|                    10|         25|        800|          5|                    25|         50|       2000|          6|                    28|         45|       1800|
#+-------+-----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
```